# Adapter selecting issue

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView which extends BaseAdapter. I have a  array list. The ListView inflates and populates correctly. I am using the flipper view to change the layout to another but the problem is when i clicked on the first item it rotate but the item at third or sixth row will also rotate
list view how can i fix it i only want the image is change of selected item

```
    ArrayList<product_data> al=new ArrayList<product_data>();
class product_data
{
    String post_title;
    String newprice;
    String oldprice;
    String image;
    String id;
    product_data(String post_title,String newprice,String oldprice,String image,String id)
    {
        this.post_title=post_title;
        this.newprice=newprice;
        this.oldprice=oldprice;
        this.image=image;
        this.id=id;

    }
}
```

to add data in arraylist

```
try {
                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(json.toString());
                JSONObject userDetails = parentObject.getJSONObject("response"); 
                JSONArray jarray=userDetails.getJSONArray("products_data");
                   for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++)
                   {
                       System.out.println("From the Dataaaa");
                       JSONObject c = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                       String details=c.getString("details");
                       String image=c.getString("image");
                       String catagory=c.getString("catagory");
                       String new_price=c.getString("new_price");
                       String title=c.getString("title");
                       String id1=c.getString("id");
                       System.out.println("from ther first image"+image);
                       System.out.println("from the sdafdfadf"+details);

                       al.add(new product_data(title, new_price, new_price, image, id1));
```

Adapter class

```
class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return al.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return al.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View singleView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int ok=position;

        if(singleView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            singleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_ist_layout,parent,false);
            System.out.println("from the if"+position);
            viewAnimator = (ViewAnimator)singleView.findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
             rootLayout = (View)singleView.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_root);
             cardFace = (View)singleView.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_card_face);
             cardBack = (View) singleView.findViewById(R.id.main_activity_card_back);
        }

            System.out.println("from the else");


        System.out.println("Position in else"+position);
        product_data a=al.get(position);
        TextView tv1=(TextView)singleView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tv2=(TextView)singleView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView tv3=(TextView)singleView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            /**
             * Bind a click listener to initiate the flip transitions
             */
            viewAnimator.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) { 
                    // This is all you need to do to 3D flip

                    AnimationFactory.flipTransition(viewAnimator, FlipDirection.LEFT_RIGHT);
                }

            });



            cardFace.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("positon"+ok);
                    AnimationFactory.flipTransition(viewAnimator, FlipDirection.LEFT_RIGHT);

                }
            });


         cardBack.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AnimationFactory.flipTransition(viewAnimator, FlipDirection.LEFT_RIGHT);
                }
            });

        imgview1=(ImageView)singleView.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
         imgview1.setTag(position);
        imgview1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int position1=(Integer)v.getTag();
                  System.out.println(position1);
                  String id=al.get(position1).id;
                  System.out.println("id from the list"+id);
                Intent in=new Intent(product_list_Activity.this,rating_dialog.class);
                in.putExtra("id",id);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    ImageView   imgview2=(ImageView)singleView.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
         imgview2.setTag(position);
        imgview2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int position1=(Integer)v.getTag();
                  System.out.println(position1);
                  String id=al.get(position1).id;
                  System.out.println("id from the list"+id);
                Intent in=new Intent(product_list_Activity.this,product_review.class);
                in.putExtra("id",id);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });

        tv3.setTag(position);
        tv3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int position1=(Integer)v.getTag();
                System.out.println("from the review "+position1);
                String id=al.get(position1).id;
                globalvariables.product_id=id;
                Intent in=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),review_product_tabbar.class);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
        tv1.setText(a.post_title);
        tv2.setText("$"+a.oldprice);
        tv1.setTypeface(tf);
        tv2.setTypeface(tf);
        tv3.setTypeface(tf);
        int loader = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        ImageView image = (ImageView)singleView. findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        imgLoader.DisplayImage(a.image, loader, image);
        Animation anim = new Rotate3dAnimation(90.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, false, singleView);
        anim.setDuration(1000l);
        singleView.startAnimation(anim);


        return singleView;
    }
}
```

}
[image]

when i click on the first item it rotate and another view is coming

but when i scrolled the fourth item in below image will also rotate

[image]

i am using the on click listner on the relative views as in the code

Comment: you did start animation in getView method !!!!, do you know how expensive it is. That method will call in every time when you scroll up  for the next item

Comment: start animation is for list view layout but my concern is with the item layout check the cardback ,flipperanimation i used the 3d rotaion clas that is implemented

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewHolder for fill adapter. that may solve your issue

Example Code

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = mInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.news_by_categories_content, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.strNewsTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtNewsByCategories);


            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        NewsListByCategoriesItem obj = new NewsListByCategoriesItem(); // My Model class getting value from this
        obj = newsArray.get(position);
        holder.strNewsTitle.setText(obj.getStrNewsTitle());


        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView strNewsTitle;


    }

}
```